# Difference between “boundary” and “limit”

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, semantics

Is there a difference between the semantics of the two words *boundary* and *limit*?

Is it possible that only one of the two has an inclusive meaning regarding the set we want the limit/boundary of? Compare it to mathematics, where we speak of “open” and “closed” sets and the difference between *maximum* (= the largest value in the set) and *supremum* (= the least upper bound, must not be contained in the set).

Comment: Depending from the context, 'boundary' and 'limit' could have different meanings and usages; and parallelism between language and mathematic, generally, produces only infelicities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a *boundary* is a visible mark which shows or sets a *bound* or *limit*.

The distinction can be clearly seen in the historical development of the word, which was formed from *bound* (“limit”) plus -*ary* (“connected with, pertaining to”). ([*OEtmD*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=boundary))

However you do not normally see this distinction made between *boundary* and *bound* or *limit* except in formal, technical contexts such as the law. In common, idiomatic usage, *boundary* often means *bound* or *limit*.

The idiomatic usage of *boundary* is nothing new. Consider the lexicographer’s complaint from the 1828 [*Webster’s Dictionary*](http://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/boundary):

> This word is thus used as synonymous with bound. But the real sense is, a visible mark designating a limit. Bound is the limit itself or furthest point of extension, and may be an imaginary line; but boundary is the thing which ascertains the limit; *terminus*, not *finis*. … But the two words are, in ordinary use, confounded.

Here, from the [*Macmillan Dictionary*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/boundary), are two sentences in which *boundary* is used in a sense which is not easily interchangeable with *limit*:

> - The *boundary* between fact and fiction in her writing is often blurred.
> - The Una River forms a natural *boundary* between the two countries.

And here, from Shakespeare courtesy of the 1913 [*Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary*](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=limit&use1913=on), are three sentences in which *limit* is used in a poetic sense not easily interchangeable with *boundary*, to mean not the bound but the entire space or time delimited:

> - The archdeacon hath divided it / Into three limits very equally.
> - The dateless limit of thy dear exile.
> - The limit of your lives is out.

Answer (score 5):

According to the *Merriam-Webster* dictionary a boundary is something that indicates a limit, not a limit in and of itself.  This agrees with my intuitive understanding of the two. Boundary lines are lines that mark the limits of the field, etc.

Comment: This answer goes beyond the limit of my understanding. Are you saying that a *boundary* is a "concrete thing", serving as an indicator of the abstract concept *limit*? That sounds an unlikely proposition to me. The difference is largely a matter of idiomatic usage - your land has *boundaries*, for example, while your imagination has *limits*. Anyway, this has nothing to do with OP's question about whether either or both words *include* themselves within the bounded/limited scope.

Comment: I don't know about your imagination, but mine knows no bounds.

Answer (score 0):

OP’s idea that *boundary* and *limit* might have different meanings in relation to “inclusivity” of the margin itself is interesting, but incorrect.

In most contexts (“tennis court *boundary* lines”, “pushing things to the *limit*”, etc.), it doesn’t really matter what you call the edge/perimeter/periphery. You have to go *beyond* it to be “outside” whatever it defines.

There’s related discussion on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37746/2637) regarding the meaning of “*inner* perimeter”.